# ServiceStack Razor Url Mapping

Tags: razor, servicestack, servicestack-bsd

Have you guys successfully done mapping already? Say, I want to map:

`/stars/alive/vedder` to: `/vedder`

I tried putting this in `web.config`:

```
<system.web>
  <urlMappings enabled="true">
    <add url="~/" mappedUrl="~/stars/alive"/>
  </urlMappings>
</system.web>
```

However, it doesn't seem to do anything. I can only still access `stars/alive/vedder`, but not directly `/vedder`.

My nuget package is servicestack.razor 3.9.55.0.

What have I done wrong? Thank you.

P.S.
I have [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17645389/servicestack-razor-web-config), not sure if they are related issues.

Comment: Yes, they are related issues. As described in my answer to your other question, you can override the default behavior with a CatchAllHandler.  It might also be possible using the web.config, I'm not able to say.

Comment: meaning url mapping is not an existing feature? Because I picked this up from another post, and someone said it would work that way in web.config...

Comment: Meaning I don't have an ASP background, and I can't speak to what's possible with web.config settings -- my servicestack projects are self hosted.

Comment: I think they are related. I tested using an existing project (v3.9.55.0) and routing / mapping works fine. Maybe worthwhile if you pasted your entire web.config (on the linked question).