# ServiceStack Razor web.config

Tags: razor, servicestack

[image: web config errors]

```
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
```

After I updated to v3.9.55.0 my web config got these errors. The website still works (surprisingly). The website obviously won't work if I remove them. I am not sure how to fix these errors or it would effect anything at all.

It seems to have something to do with SS no longer use **Razor 1.0**? Should I simply add **Razor 2.0** of `System.web.WebPages.Razor` to fix the issue or what?

Also, there is a `System.Web.Razor.Unoffical` **Razor v3.0** in the reference dlls. Is it a SS mod or MS offical beta?

You see, I am a bit confused. Where do I get some explanation of this new update? Thank you.

Comment: Which version did you upgrade from, and what method did you use to upgrade (e.g NuGet)? I've updated this morning without changing any of the web.config, and Razor references still points to v1.0.

Comment: @hhandoko, I can't remember exactly. I THINK it is from 3.9.32.0 ... I nuget'd it. It is not a biggie there. My point is, I wanna know if pointing it to 2.0 would be the correct way to fix it. And what is that Razor.Unoffical thingy?

Comment: Have you tried "Clean Solution"? It could be just the intellisense playing up. Razor.Unofficial I think because SS use a different build of Razor which removes ASP.Net MVC deps.

Comment: Perhaps if you can post your entire web.config (redact where necessary), it would help us find a solution.

Comment: Unofficial is from SS. And it works with Version 1.0 as other things are fetched from Unofficial version. Still as suggested above, complete web config will help to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the section that works fine.

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
```

It is tried and tested. Also you can check out my fsharp port of [razor rockstars](https://github.com/kunjee17/ServiceStackHeroku) along with razor rockstars, I don't know if razor rockstars is updated with latest libraries.

**UPDATE**

I checked [razor rockstars](https://github.com/ServiceStack/RazorRockstars/) I guess it is updated with latest frameworks. You should check out that too.

Best way to solve this kind of error is to use completed project instead of dll. So, you can debug the source code itself and it there is any issue you can patch back.

Please let me know if any further details required.